# Unmet dependencies. Libc6 The package system is broken

Tags: 20.04, software-installation, dpkg, dependencies, glibc

Whenever I try to upgrade or install a new package i get the following

```
ibc6-dbg: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed \
libc6-dev: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed \
           Depends: libc-dev-bin (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 is installed
libc6-i386: Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.1 is installed
```

I've tried `apt --fix-broken install`
I've tried `sudo apt-get -f  install` to force install. 
I get the same error messages in both cases.

I'm still new to Linux and would love to learn how to fix these issues without wiping the os and reinstalling

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1315906/edit) to show the complete output of `sudo apt update` and then of `sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: As user535733 has said; you likely had warnings in your `sudo apt update` output, OR it provides clues as to a problem. A quick scan of the packages expected and I see 9.2 matching your =9.2 for `libc6-dbg`, so it could be the source isn't showing or error in `sudo apt update`, or your used mirror isn't *up-to-date* and needs checking (you start with `sudo apt update` detail as you update your software lists on your hardware) etc...

Answer (score 31):

I had similar issue on freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04.2 desktop 64bit, the difference is that libc6 ...9.3 was installed but my packages (g++ build-essential etc) could not be installed beceause libc6-dev could not be installed because it required libc6 ...9.2 which was older then the one installed

```
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.31-0ubuntu9.2) but 2.31-0ubuntu9.3 is to be installed
```

So I just **downgraded libc6 (and libc-bin too, because it seems very related to me)** to version 2.31-0ubuntu9.2 this way:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

Now my packages could install :) so it seems to work, let's see if we don't have much problems - but I guess not because this is a tiny change in libc (on the other side libc is very important)

### BUT I DON'T KNOW WHAT WILL HAPPEN IN THE FUTURE:

- Will it in future updates hold this package fixed to still old version?
- Does anyone know how to unfix this version?
- Even if I could somehow unfix it from this version, then will ubuntu have this issue in the future?
- Does anyone know if it is some bug in Ubuntu packaging repository? I repeat: this was on a totally fresh Ubuntu 20.04 desktop

Some other places to look for inspiration:

- https://serverfault.com/a/993629/445123
- https://serverfault.com/a/1005063/445123

Comment: Man, you nailed it. Thanks!

Comment: can you please file a bug on launchpad? I had a similar issue. got too much invested in setup now to potentially break - it seems like a wrong dependency declaration in packages - UPDATE : https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/1926918 seems this is tracked.

Comment: I am really not happy doing this but it works for now.

Comment: thanks!, I had this issue when using the system76 driver ppa. `apt-cache policy linux-libc-dev` showed a non ubuntu version of this package vendored by system67 that declared incompatability with `linux-libc-dev:i386` maybe wrong, anyway, the policy output gave me what version to downgrade to

Answer (score 6):

I would like to add to the answer of *Tomeg*, that downgrading with *aptitude* helped me to keep my packages depending on *libc6* installed. When downgrading with:

```
sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.
```

*apt* would also uninstall all my packages depending on *libc6*.

```
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  libc6
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 downgraded, 206 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

As I described [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1372227/1194287) this did help since *aptitude* offered me different options:

```
 sudo aptitude install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
```

I had to decline the first two options (2x n) and then the third was to solely downgrade (y) without uninstalling other packages.

Comment: Thank you. With this command I could downgrade lib6 and install build essential.

Comment: Thankyou. The number of apps to be uninstalled nearly gave me a heartattack. Why can't these repositories keep in sync ?

Comment: This answer saves lives. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Apart from reinstalling a specific version of `libc`, you may need to check out the `apt` sources file in `/etc/apt/sources.list` and see whether the `apt` source matches your Ubuntu OS version. If the versions don't match, you need to replace the `sources.list` code name with the right code name of Ubuntu, update `apt` source, then reinstall `libc` or `gcc`.

Answer (score 0):

These instructions helped me. You know you need to fix the package dependency for `libc6` so:

1. Find available versions for `libc6`:

   ```
   apt show -a libc6
   ```
2. From the list you see after running the above command
   install a version (the one you need). For example, if you want version `2.31-0ubuntu9.7`, run:

   ```
   sudo apt install libc6="2.31-0ubuntu9.7"
   ```
3. Now run:

   ```
   sudo apt install build-essential
   ```

Comment: Messing with the default `libc6` version might not be a good idea.. 