# Ubuntu 22.04 issue, cannot install libc6-dev ... you have held broken packages

Tags: nvidia, cuda, glibc, tensorflow

I do not know how to fix the following, and it's causing a huge delay on my progress on a research project:

```
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt-get install libc6-dev
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libc6-dev : Depends: libc6 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3) but 2.35-0ubuntu3.1 is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Edit 1: Thanks for your comments so far, I apologize for the readability of the following

```
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2 libc-bin=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc6:i386 libdb1-compat libnss-nisplus:i386 libnss-nis:i386 libcrypt1:i386
  libnss-nisplus libnss-nis libcrypt1

Package libc-bin is a virtual package provided by:
  libc-bin:i386 2.35-0ubuntu3 (= 2.35-0ubuntu3)
You should explicitly select one to install.

E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc6' was not found
E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc-bin' was not found
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt install libc-bin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libc-bin is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc6:i386 libdb1-compat libnss-nisplus:i386 libnss-nis:i386 libcrypt1:i386
  libnss-nisplus libnss-nis libcrypt1

E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc6' was not found
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo aptitude install libc6
sudo: aptitude: command not found
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt-get aptitude
E: Invalid operation aptitude
```

(so at this point I installed aptitude-common)

```
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt install libc6=2.31-0ubuntu9.2
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package libc6 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libc6:i386 libdb1-compat libnss-nisplus:i386 libnss-nis:i386 libcrypt1:i386
  libnss-nisplus libnss-nis libcrypt1

E: Version '2.31-0ubuntu9.2' for 'libc6' was not found
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo apt install libc6
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
libc6 is already the newest version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo aptitude install libc6
libc6 is already installed at the requested version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1)
libc6 is already installed at the requested version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
                                         
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo aptitude install libc6-bin
Couldn't find any package whose name or description matched "libc6-bin"
Unable to apply some actions, aborting
(base) chaztikov@priority:~/git/modulus$ sudo aptitude install libc-bin
libc-bin is already installed at the requested version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1)
libc-bin is already installed at the requested version (2.35-0ubuntu3.1)
No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.
```

At this point, I am not sure what I should do, my intuition is that it has something to do with virtual packages...?

Should I try to install using, for example, selections from
https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libc-bin
and
https://pkgs.org/search/?q=libc6

Comment: maybe this helps? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1315906/unmet-dependencies-libc6-the-package-system-is-broken

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)

Comment: Always run `sudo apt update` and `sudo apt upgrade` before you install packages.

Comment: Thanks for the responses, I checked both links, installed aptitude-common, and tried to use it to directly install libc6  and libc-bin (libc-bin is a virtual package provided by libc-bin:i386=2.35-0ubuntu3)  I'm not sure what to make of this virtual package stuff.

Comment: But my attempts did not resolve the issue

Comment: Your CUDA tag suggest that you are in the maze of twisty little dependencies created by the CUDA dep installation.  There are CUDA install answers on this site using the .run script which avoids those. Starting fresh might be easier than cleanup at this point. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1077061/how-do-i-install-nvidia-and-cuda-drivers-into-ubuntu/1077063#1077063
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1219761/cuda-10-2-different-installation-paths/1244010#1244010

Comment: Thanks! Indeed I am.  I don't think it helped much that I started a fresh install with lambda stack with which I had no familiarity.  Just to clarify: reinstall the entire OS? Can I fix it using a bootable drive?

Comment: After polluting the OS with foreign versions of libraries, executables, etc. best to reinstall the OS.  Cleaning things out will take much longer to identify and replace the non-standard items.  Treat CUDA as an app -- if it really requires special library versions, put them into the app install location, not a system location.  Note the .run file wires in the /usr/local/cuda-xx location, so to avoid using sudo, take temp ownership of /usr/local so you can let the .run script as a user create the directory it insists upon (you cannot even create the dir in advance with your user ownership).

Comment: This might be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443583/gdb-installation-error-libc6-dev and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1434778/cant-install-libc6i386-on-jammy .