# Can't install libc6:i386 on Jammy

Tags: package-management, 22.04, lts, bug-reporting

Up-to-date `amd64` Jammy installation.

```
% cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS \n \l

% dpkg --print-foreign-architectures
i386

% dpkg -l libc6
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version         Architecture Description
+++-==============-===============-============-=================================
ii  libc6:amd64    2.35-0ubuntu3.1 amd64        GNU C Library: Shared libraries
in  libc6:i386     <none>          i386         (no description available)
```

As far as I could understand, following prevents `libc6:i386` installation:

```
% sudo dpkg -i libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb
...
(Reading database ... 228990 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libc6:i386 (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb (--install):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libc6/NEWS.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libc6:i386
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.35-0ubuntu3.1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 libc6_2.35-0ubuntu3.1_i386.deb
```

Two questions:

1. How do I revert `in` status of i386 package in dpkg? Having package half-installed makes system look untidy, that's quite sad;
2. Is above a temporary bug in Ubuntu packaging? Do I submit a bug to Canonical? I don't want trying manual removal of offending `NEWS.Debian` file, as I don't want to risk system stability and who knows which further conflicts are there ...

---

As a PS, running `ubuntu-bug libc6` eventually produces quite "funny" output:

```
% ubuntu-bug libc6                           

*** Collecting problem information

The collected information can be sent to the developers to improve the
application. This might take a few minutes.
.......

*** Problem in libc6

The problem cannot be reported:

This does not seem to be an official Ubuntu package.
```

Comment: Where did you get libc6?

Comment: @David from packages.ubuntu.com?

Comment: This might be the same problem as https://askubuntu.com/questions/1443583/gdb-installation-error-libc6-dev and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1429323/ubuntu-22-04-issue-cannot-install-libc6-dev-you-have-held-broken-packages .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turned out, for some reason, my `sources.list` was missing `jammy-updates` section (it had both `jammy` and `jammy-security` sections).

After I've added

```
deb http://mirror/ubuntu/ jammy-updates main restricted
```

and similar entries for `universe/multiverse`, I was able to install `libc6:i386` via basic `apt-get update/install` way.

Comment: I got hit by a similar bug, I was unable to apt install valgrind because of some unmet dependency in libc6:i386. I checked my sources-list, and indeed there was no jammy-updates section. After adding it, I was able to install valgrind without problems. Thanks so much!! I have no clue why it was missing the updates section in sources.list, this was a fresh install 22.04.1 LTS with some additional PPAs but not much more.